# NSTextField label: dynamically change content and grow width to fit

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

If I drag a `Label` (of class `NSTextField`) into a view in Interface Builder, and then attempt to set its `stringValue` dynamically like so:

```
self.testingLabel.stringValue = "Labels are really really really long"
```

Then most of the label will be cut off.

[image: cut off text]

How can I make the label grow to fit its content without wrapping/scrolling?

I have tried using this custom class but it doesn't work.

```
class AutogrowTextField: NSTextField {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: NSSize {
        get {
            var frame = self.frame;
            frame.size.width = CGFloat.max;

            // Calculate new height within the frame
            // with practically infinite height.
            let width = self.cell!.cellSizeForBounds(frame).width

            Swift.print(width)
            NSBeep()

            Swift.print(self.frame.width)

            return NSMakeSize(width, frame.size.height)
        }
    }

    // you need to invalidate the layout on text change, else it wouldn't grow by changing the text
    override func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
        super.textDidChange(notification)
        self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Essentially I just want the default behaviour of an HTML document like this:

```
<p id="dynamic">Hi</p>

<script>
    document.getElementByID("dynamic").innerHtml = "Something really really really long"
</script>
```

This is extremely painful for me as while I am new to Mac OS X and Cocoa, I am not a 'beginner' programmer.

In case it helps here is the contents of the attributes inspector. (it should just be all default values)

[image: attributes]

**Yes, auto layout is enabled**

[image: enabled]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your NIB or storyboard is configured to use auto layout? That would be a checkbox on the File inspector.

The reason I ask is that the Attributes inspector would have a "Preferred Width _ First Runtime Layout Width" checkbox, immediately below the "Uses Single Line Mode" checkbox. It doesn't, which makes me think that auto layout is not enabled.

If you're not using auto layout, then you are responsible for either setting the label's frame size or, more simply, telling it to size itself to fit its content by calling `sizeToFit()`.

If you're using auto layout, then the standard `NSTextField` already computes its `intrinsicContentSize` based on its string content. The problem is almost certainly with whatever other constraints you may have set on the view. You need to make sure that the auto layout system is free to adjust the label's width. So, you must not set an explicit width constraint. Or, if you have, say, both a leading and trailing spacing constraint, you need to make sure the label's compression-resistance priority is high enough to push the other related views out or compress them. Etc.

Comment: Yes auto layout is enabled, and I haven't added any constraints. Are you sure it will grow by default? I thought it was clip/wrap/stick to original size by default. I didn't imagine it would be this hard to make it grow/expand though.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Also, try adding constraints for, say, leading and top spacing to superview (and no others) to the label. You can also try setting the label's "Layout" attribute to Truncates and enable Uses Single Line Mode.

Comment: Aha! So I suppose by default auto layout assumes that `no constraints` really means `fixed position/everything constrained`, and so by only adding top and left/leading constraints that forces the engine to make bottom/right constraints more flexible? I must admit I haven't dealt with auto layout much before so reading up about it would probably help :P

Comment: On the Size inspector for a view which has no constraints, you'll see a statement that Xcode will add constraints at build time. It's not the auto layout system itself assuming that no constraints means fixed position. For example, if you add a view programmatically and turn off `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` but don't add any constraints, the view will be positioned arbitrarily. (In practice, it goes to 0,0.) If it has intrinsic size, it will take on that size. Otherwise, its size will be arbitrary, too. (Again, 0,0 in practice.)